# ASP.NET Core - How to resolve System.FormatException Message=String '2023-04-09 10:59' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime

In my ASP.NET Core application, I have given expiry_date that has the datatype of a string in this format:   "expiry_date": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"

So I want to convert it into DateTime datatype of this format:  2019-08-24 10:59

So I did:

```
var expiryDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(initializationResponse.expiry_date, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

However, I got this error:

```
System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=String '2023-04-09 10:59' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
```

How do I get this resolve?

Comment: You're providing `DateTime.ParseExact` with a format of "yyyy/MM/dd" but a value of either "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z" (your claim) or "2023-04-09 10:59" (from the error message). Neither of those values match the format you're trying to use for parsing. Note that a `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format - there's no such concept as " convert it into DateTime datatype of this format: 2019-08-24 10:59". You parse to a `DateTime`, and if you need a specific string representation later, you specify that when converting the `DateTime` to a string again.

Comment: Where did `"expiry_date": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z"` come from? If you have a JSON string, it's better to use a JSON parser to parse the entire string into proper objects and types. Dates in JSON use the ISO8901 standard. You can define `expiry_date` as a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` in your DTO and ASP.NET Core will map it automatically

Answer (score -1):

Try this

DateTime.ParseExact("2023-04-09", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: I don't see how that's going to help the OP, who doesn't *have* a string in that format, and doesn't look like they *want* a string in that format.